# What do I need to do to get Software Updater to work though I'm connected and can browse the internet?

Tags: 14.04, networking, updates, update-manager

What do I need to do to get Software Updater to work though I'm connected and can browse the internet?

Each time I try to update I'm met with the message

```
Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection.
```

My browsers work just fine and I know I'm connected. However, updater is not. Now I see on my desktop menu bar this caution symbol (⚠) that when click states along the lines that my software needs updated.

I'm using a wired connection through a router to a modem to the ISP. I'm using Ubutnu 14.04 LTS. The icon indicates that my software is out of date. It's a vicious circle, how do I fix this?

Edit:
I would post the paste from terminal when I used

```
grep --ignore-case trusty-updates /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but it says I need ten reputation to post more than two links. It lists the us.ubuntu.com links six times and lists them in pairs saying main restricted, universe and multiverse.

Comment: What's the output of sudo apt-get update?

Comment: What is the server you're using?  [Edit] your question and copy-paste the output of `grep --ignore-case trusty-updates /etc/apt/sources.list`, please...

Answer (score 0):

Please click the "check" box, which is next to the "update" box.  Sometimes that detangles the updater.

Comment: There is no check box next to any update box anywhere in any of this mess by the means you responded with.

Answer (score 0):

More than a year late I know but I have just had exactly this problem and in my case fortunately the Software Updater was just giving a bad error message. The message that it can't connect to the internet should actually say that it can't access some of the PPAs in your `Software & Updates - Other Software` list.

Click on the error message's details link and you'll see which one(s) is/are causing issues.

Now go into the `Software and Updates` dialog, and uncheck the bad PPAs in the `Other Software` list. It'll demand your root password.

Then close it and the Software Updater should run fine.

Obviously it won't update the software that came from that PPA, so you'll have to look into that yourself (if you need it updating).